# Defining new command for canceling ignore distance in the math mode?

Tags: math-mode, spacing

How can I cancel the ignored distance in the math mode by defining a new command and use that command wherever I want?
I mean, for example, in

```
\begin{align}
x^2+y^2\\
''Hello world!"
\end{align}
```

output of second line is "*Helloworld!*".
I want to define for example \mycommand,such that output of \mycommand{''Hello world!"} is (not italic, with space)

```
Hello world!
```

Comment: Does `\text{``Hello world!''}` do what you want?

Comment: `align` is math mode, so `Hello World`  is typeset as `$Hello World$` as math, you could use `\text{hello world}` but there is no alignment here (no `&`) so you should not be using `align` at all, what is the intended output?

Comment: @SandyG,, \text command, change the font to font of main document, but I want to get math font and regular text.

Comment: If by "math font" you mean italics then you can use `\mathit{Hello World}`.

Comment: @niksirat math fonts are explicitly designed not to produce regular text they produce adjacent letters that look like a product of variables not a word, it isn't just the inter word space gone. use `\textit{Hello world}` if you want text italic. But none of this is should be in an align as in your fragment.

Comment: My purpose is generating upright text with spaces in math mode without change the math font.

Comment: You may just want to add your spaces manually: `\mathrm{``Hello\ world!"}`

Comment: @SandyG, In my Maple book , I have to use that many time, so it is very hard to create space manually.